# Can magnetism from a custom cooling pad interfere with the laptop?

Tags: laptop, fan, cooling-pad

I made a custom cooling pad for my laptop and want to connect the fan below my laptop with the help of tape to the vent at the bottom of my laptop.

Can the magnetic waves produced by the fans motor damage components inside my laptop?

Comment: i think the motor as well as the laptop has better shielding.

Comment: I edited your post, feel free to revert the changes or edit it again, but please ensure that the title reflects what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Nope; your fan won't produce a strong enough magnetic field to have an effect.

Answer (score 1):

Laptops contain many sources of electromagnetic emission like voltage converters, regulators, speakers, fans and magnetic drives.

Your laptop should not be impaired by external electromagnetic sources like a fan in your case.